# Extracting and summarize raster for a large polygon set

Tags: raster, r, polygon

I have a large multipolygon (5x5km grids) file (1.23 million polygons) that I would like to exact raster data to each polygon. Specifically I want to calculate the fractal dimensions (a user defined function), Morans I (from the `raster` package), and the mean NDVI value of all the pixels that fall into each polygon.

The raster covers the extent of Australia. Each band has an associated date (919 total bands in the raster). Importantly, all polygons need only one specific band.

However, this loop takes such a long time (roughly 2 seconds per polygon). The crop command is what makes the loop run slowly. What is the best way to speed this loop up?

Below is the basic for loop

```
#adding column for final values to be returned
#spdf3_buffed is a sf object

spdf3_buffed$FractID <- 0  
spdf3_buffed$meanNDVI$Moran <- 0
spdf3_buffed$meanNDVI <- 0

for (i in 1:nrow(spdf3_buffed)){
  print(i) 
  spSubset <- spdf3_buffed[i,]
  BandNumber <-spSubset$BandNumber    
  r <- raster(MODIS_raster_location,band=BandNumber)
  cropped_raster <- crop(r, st_bbox(spSubset))
  b <- as.numeric(fractalD(cropped_raster))
  c <- as.numeric(Moran(cropped_raster))
  layermeans <- cellStats(cropped_raster, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE)
  u <- mean(layermeans)
  spdf3_buffed$FractID[[i]] <- b
  spdf3_buffed$Moran[[i]] <- c
  spdf3_buffed$meanNDVI[[i]] <- u
}

write.csv(spdf3_buffed,file="test.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the slowest part of the code is the call to `Moran`. I am using `raster::extent` in lue of `sf::st_bbox` which seems to make a difference. I also moved the for loop into an `lapply`.

Let's add libraries and create some example data. I would recommend reading the data into R as a stack, and index out of the stack, rather than repeatedly reading a raster at each iteration. I am using the nc data that comes with sf and adding a "BandNumber" to emulate your code. This is what is being indexed from the stack using double brackets.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)

nc <- st_cast(st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", 
              package="sf")), "POLYGON")
 
i=500; j=500
r <- do.call(raster::stack, replicate(20, 
             raster::raster(matrix(sample(c(0,1), i*j, replace=TRUE), i, j)))) 
    extent(r) <- extent(nc)
      proj4string(r) <- st_crs(nc)$proj4string

  plot(r[[1]])
    plot(st_geometry(nc), add=TRUE)

nc$BandNumber <- sample(1:nlayers(r), nrow(nc), replace=TRUE)
```

Here is our call to `lapply` for implementing a loop. It looked like you wanted an echo so, I added one using `cat`, `Sys.sleep` and `flush.console` which is a trick to get the message to actually print. Since you do not tell us where `fractalD` comes from, I am using the `lsm_c_frac_mn` function from landscapemetrics. I would not use `cellStats` when you can simply pass a vector of raster values to `mean` with na.rm=TRUE.

```
s <- lapply(1:nrow(nc), function(i) {
  cat("processing", i, "of", nrow(nc), "\n")
    Sys.sleep(0.01)
      flush.console()
  rsub <- crop(r[[nc[i,]$BandNumber]], extent(nc[i,]))
    fd <- as.data.frame(landscapemetrics::lsm_c_frac_mn(rsub))[,6][2]
      c(fd, as.numeric(Moran(rsub)), mean(rsub[], na.rm=TRUE)) } )
```

The results are a list object so, we can collapse them into a data.frame and join back to the polygon data.

```
( s <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", s)) )
  names(s) <- c("FractID", "Moran", "meanNDVI")  
   s$CNTY_ID <- nc$CNTY_ID        
     nc <- dplyr::left_join(nc, s)
```

With over a million observations, this is still going to take quite some time. I would consider breaking the problem into multiple pieces. You could also try to multi-thread the problem but, breaking your polygon data into multiple pieces and running each subset in a difference instance of R will speed this up considerably, especially if you have the cores to also support multi-threading using something like `future.apply::future_lapply` (parallel version of `lapply`).

Comment: This is a great answer. I am looking through it now. I have access to a computational server and know this will take some time. Any suggestions how to put your code into parallel?

Comment: @Douglas I would add that if your are still seeing a bottleneck with crop you could coerce into a terra rast class and use `terra::crop`. Following my example; `terra::crop(rast(r[[nc[i,]$BandNumber]]), terra::ext(vect(nc[i,])))`